# Is this hadith found in Musannaf of Abd al-Razzaq?

Tags: hadith, reference-request

This hadith in found [Sunan an-Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/urn/1000780) which is

> "Some of the Companions of the Prophet (ﷺ) were looking for (water for) Wudu'. The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: 'Do any of you have water?' He put his hand in the water and said: 'Perform Wudu' in the Name of Allah.' I saw the water coming out from between his fingers until they had all performed Wudu'." Thabit said: "I said to Anas: 'How many did you see?' He said: 'About seventy.'"

This isnad has Abdur-Razzaq and Mamar bin Rashid so i am wondering if it is in Musannaf of Abd al-Razzaq and if it is not, why not? surely he would have documented it.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is in al-Mosnnaf in the chapter: كتاب الجامع  and sub chapter  باب النبوة (see [here](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&idfrom=19578&idto=19582&bk_no=73&ID=2459) which is my primery source) it is quoted twice (the second is only quoting a different narrator chain):

> 20535 أخبرنا عبد الرزاق ، قال : أخبرنا معمر ، عن ثابت ، وقتادة ، عن أنس ، قال : نظر بعض أصحاب النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم وضوءا فلم يجده ، فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم : " هاهنا ماء ؟ " فرأيت النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم وضع يده في الإناء الذي فيه الماء ، ثم قال : " توضأ بسم الله " ، فرأيت الماء يفور من بين أصابعه ، والقوم يتوضئون ، حتى توضئوا من عند آخرهم ، قال ثابت : فقلت لأنس كم تراهم كانوا ؟ قال : نحوا من سبعين رجلا .
>
> [ ص: 277 ] 20536 أخبرنا عبد الرزاق ، عن معمر ، عن الأعمش ، عن مسلم بن صبيح ، عن أبي هريرة ، وأبي سعيد مثله .

You may find further a similar narration on the next page:

> 20537  أخبرنا عبد الرزاق قال : أخبرنا معمر ، عن عوف ، عن أبي رجاء العطاردي ، عن عمران بن الحصين ، قال : كان رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم في سفر هو وأصحابه فأصابهم عطش شديد ، فأرسل النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم رجلين من أصحابه - علي والزبير أو غيرهما - فقال : " إنكما ستجدان امرأة في مكان كذا وكذا معها بعير عليه مزادتان ، فأتيا بها " ، فأتيا المرأة ، فوجداها قد ركبت بين مزادتيها على البعير ، فقالا لها : أجيبي رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ، فقالت : من رسول الله ؟ أهذا الصابئ ؟ قالا : هذا الذي تعنين وهو رسول الله حقا ، فجاءا بها ، فأمر النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فجعل في إناء من مزادتيها شيئا ، ثم قال ما شاء الله أن يقول ، ثم أعاد الماء في المزادتين ، ثم أمر بعرى المزادتين ففتحت ، ثم أمر الناس فملئوا آنيتهم وأسقيتهم ، فلم يدعوا إناء ولا سقاء إلا ملئوه ، فقال عمران : فكان يخيل إلي أنهما لم يزدادا إلا امتلاء ، قال : فأمر النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم بثوبها فبسط ، ثم أصحابه ، فجاءوا من أزوادهم حتى ملأ لها ثوبها ، ثم قال : " اذهبي فإنا لم نأخذ من مائك شيئا ، [ ص: 278 ] ولكن الله سقانا " ، فجاءت أهلها ، فأخبرتهم ، فقالت : جئتكم من عند أسحر الناس ، أو إنه لرسول الله حقا ، قال : فجاء أهل ذلك الصرم فأسلموا كلهم .

All these narrations where reported via Ma'amar:
20535 'Abdurrazaaq-> Ma'amar-> Thabet and Qatadah -> Anas.
20536 'Abdurrazaaq-> Ma'amar->al-A'mash -> Muslim ibn Sabyyh -> Abu Hurrairah and abu Sa'id.
20537 'Abdurrazaaq-> Ma'amar-> 'Aowf -> abi Raja' al-'Utaridy -> 'Imran ibn al-Hossayn.

These ahadith can be found [here](https://ia800709.us.archive.org/21/items/FP152501/09_152509.pdf) as hadith #24159-#24161 in the version of al-Mosannaf provided by al-Waqfiyya.

The hadith also appears via a totally different chain in [al-Muwatta'](https://sunnah.com/urn/500630) -source for later narrations- not via Ma'amar, in Sahih al-Bukhari [1](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/82) and [2](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/4/35) [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/43/5) [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/734980) and [Sunan an-Nasa-i](https://sunnah.com/urn/1100760) all these on the authority of Anas ibn Malik and all the listed books rely on the version of al-Muwatta' in first place which was reported via the chain:
Malik-> Ishaaq ibn 'Abdullah ibn abi Talhah -> Anas ibn Malik.